# Cloud Server Kernel Error

Tags: centos, ssh, boot, yum, ftp

Due to a yum update error I've got my server stuck unable to boot due to a Kernel issue. I can boot the server into CentOS7 Recovery Mode however I can't FTP in to get my files off the server. Does anyone know how to get FTP or SSH started/opened in recovery mode or to repair the Kernel.

I can't get yum to run as I get an error that it can't find yummain due to being in recovery mode

[image: Kernel Panic Description]

This is running under VMware and the first line of the Kernel Panic reads

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

Comment: Some context to your Kernel issue, please?

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson I've edited my post to include a screen grab

Comment: Text would be much more useful. See https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22812

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get the server back up and running

Put centOS disk in system, rebooted, entered install process then quit. From there I could select a previous version of the kernel and boot the system

Comment: This answer would be better (more useful to others who run into the same problem) if you [edit] it to explain in more detail how you rescued your system. I presume when you say "quit", that you dropped into a root shell and that you then re-configured your boot-loader (GRUB?) to boot the previous kernel version.